# JAXB same code different behavior

Tags: java, jaxb

Hello everyone I have the code below and in a standAlone project the unmarshall works perfect and the code inserted in other project I get a error.

Code:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Form.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
Form form = (Form) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringWriter(xmlstring));
```

Error:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"Form"). Expected elements are <{http://www.site1.pt/}Form>
```

The stranger thing is the namespace (http://www.site1.pt/) I don't use specific in the code of form but I use in other parts of my other project , so why when I put this part of the code in my other project it's assuming the namespace?

I have a package called pt.interfaces that there has a file package-info.java I didn't had a package-info in my package pt.interfaces.form.

I tried to create a package-info.java in my package pt.interfaces.form and if I change the the namespace (http://www.test.pt/) the error change:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"Form"). Expected elements are <{http://www.test.pt/}Form>
```

If in my package-info.java (pt.interfaces.form) I change the namespace to nothing "" ou remove it I don't get error but the object don't have the xml values.

Any ideias?
Thanks

Comment: Check if there is a `package-info.java` in the corresponding package in the first or second project. `package-info.java` may contain the `@XmlSchema` which may define the namespace.

Comment: Thanks for the replay lexicore. I'll explain in the answer!